# Properties of complex exponentials.

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, transcendental-numbers

I saw the following property in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Complex_plane)
\begin{align}
(e^z)^n=e^{zn} \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. It's possible to change the $e$ in $(1)$ to some other  number ? For example:

\begin{align}
(a^z)^n=a^{zn} 
\end{align}

where $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ is maybe a real number or even complex? Or even change the conditions on $z$ and $n$.

Another thing related to $(1)$. [Gelfond's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) says that $a^b$ is transcendental if $a$ is algebraic and $a \neq 1$, $a \neq 0$ and $b$ is irrational. For example $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is transcendental. One result from this theorem is that $e^\pi$ [(Gelfond constant)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant) is transcendental. Noting that:

\begin{align} 
& e^{i\pi} = -1 \\ 
& (e^{i\pi})^{-i} = (-1)^{-i}\\ 
& e^{\pi} = (-1)^{-i}
\end{align}

since $(-1)$ is algebraic and $-i$ is irrational the theorem applies. But in the second line above didn't we just violate the property $(1)$ because $-i$ in not an integer?

Comment: Given two complex numbers $a,z\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a^{z}$ is given by $a^z=e^{z\log a}$, where $\log$ is the multivalued complex logarithm $\log a=\ln\left|a\right|+i\arg a$. Sometimes the principal version is used with $\operatorname{Log}a=\ln\left|a\right|+i\operatorname{Arg} a$ instead. So, you are correct that $e$ can be replaced with $a$.

Comment: That should say $a,z\in\mathbb{C}$. I am typing up an answer now to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two complex numbers $a,z\in\mathbb{C}$, we have $a^{z}=e^{z\log a}$. You are correct that for any $a,z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\left(a^{z}\right)^{n}=a^{zn}$, which can be verified by substituting $e^{z\log a}$. If $n$ is no longer an integer, then it is no longer true because it becomes multivalued.

Using your example, we have
\begin{align*}
\left(-1\right)^{-i}=e^{-i\log\left(-1\right)}=e^{-i\left(\ln\left|-1\right|+i\arg\left(-1\right)\right)}=e^{-i\left(0+i\arg\left(-1\right)\right)}=e^{-i^{2}\left(\pi+2\pi k\right)}=e^{\pi+2\pi k},\,k\in\mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I'd add a comment that we are taking the branch of logarithm for which $\log(-1) = \pi+2\pi k$, otherwise it doesn't make much sense since it should be a set then.

Comment: Sorry if this a dumb question but... is true that $(a^n)^z=a^{zn}$ where $n$ is integer and $z$ is complex? I did the following $a^n=e^{n\ln a} \implies (a^n)^z = e^{nz\ln a} = a^{nz}$. And $arg(z) = -i\ln(z/|z|)$ is true? This complex part with the arguments, principal branches, multivalues, properties of logarithms/expoents don't apply anymore etc. it's all new and confusing to me, especially because I just read stuff online, I don't have a classes involving this topic.